# When going digital what are some things to be aware of?

Tags: system

We currently have a normal analogue system that supports about 25 channels of sound input.  We want to switch our sound board to digital.  Is this straight forward or is there things we need to be aware of?

Comment: why do you want to switch?

Comment: Well, some of the pervailing thought is that our older sound board is old (it was just refurbished a couple of years ago).  Also, we want to integrate more flexibility to allow for better sound control.  Multiple instruments, voices, sound tracks, videos, etc.

Comment: @Natster - Interesting question, but it's difficult to know where to start with this. Do you need to know how to identify an equivalent system? What system do you have now? Are you recording to tape, or sending an analog feed from a mixing board to a DAW? Of do you just want to discuss the issue? (If the latter, this board is the wrong place for a discussion thread.)

Comment: we currently have a Mackie Bus Mixie Console 4 Bus Mixing Console connects to Alesis Nano Compressor connects to Alesis Dual 1/3 precision Equalizer connects to Alesis Midi Verb 4 : 18 bit ext. range signal processor.

Comment: Identifying a good replacement is what I would be after for the mixing board.

Comment: And or things I might need to consider when changing over.